# javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have two three text boxes.

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="100" />
<input type="text" name="test" value="250" />

<input type="text" name="totalList" value="" />
```

What I would like to happen is for the `totalList` textbox to have all the values of the textboxes before seperated by a comma, so its value would be `100, 250`. The reason it is in an array is because I am going to be extracting from a database and I do not know how many items there will be, I just know they will all have a price.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the array.join method.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("test");
var values = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
    values.push(elements[i].value);

document.getElementsByName("totalList")[0].value = values.join();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UqUMs/7/

Comment: how can i make it update the totalList value whenever something is changed?

Comment: @Jake I have updated the jsfiddle example so that it will update when the text boxes lose focus.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array (of textboxes), create a comma separated string of the values, and set this as the value of the `total` textbox:

```
var textboxes = document.forms[formName].elements["text"];
var commaSeparatedStr = "";
for(var i=0; i<textboxes.length; i++)
{
   commaSeparatedStr+= textboxes[i].value;
}
document.forms[formName].elements[totalList].value = commaSeparatedStr;
```

And call this code whenever you want: body.onload, on a button click, (if textboxes can be added dynamically) on dynamic addition/removal of a textbox etc.

I have given a javascript solution because you have tagged so. Depending on whether the textboxes can be added dynamically or not, you may also do this on the server side.